# My stepper motor has resistance, but does not respond to commands

Tags: troubleshooting, stepper-driver

I have a RAMPS 1.4 setup and I am trying to get things to move.
I have a DRV2258 attached to it, and when I power on the 12 V power supply the stepper gets some resistance.

However, when I try to send commands in Repetier Host, the stepper doesn't even move. Only the led on the Arduino Mega flickers (as it should, as it is instructed in the G-code).

I have:

- Baud rate set to 115200
- The stepper driver also has 1.7 amps, which seems to be correct.

Comment: Hi Wessel, welcome again! Like the previous question, your question is not very clear. Please look into [ask] to create a good question. You could add information on the research you have done and how you isolated the problem. E.g. you should test this for a single stepper first, also explain how you [tuned the stepper drivers](https://reprap.org/wiki/Pololu_stepper_driver_board#DRV8825).

Comment: Alright! I will do that in the evening

Comment: Does the stepper click? When you back drive the stepper (e.g. pushing the extruder side to side, or pushing the bed back and forth) do you get a distinct *thud* each time you move it? It could be that only 1 phase is getting powered. Do yo have a multimeter? Did you check the voltage drop across the phases? Is the motor getting hot? Are you sure you put the driver in the correct way? Is it doing this for one axis or all axies?

Comment: It is fixed. It were just some cheap broken chinese rip offs, bought legit ones and now it works like a charm!